# Import "..." could not be resolved MacOs - Environment

Tags: python, pip, homebrew

I have a repetitive problems almost in all my projects. I use separate environments for each project, then I install related libraries for them. I used `pip` or `brew` for installation. But most of the time I had this error: `Import "..." could not be resolved` I'm sure I installed those packages because I see them in `pip list`

For example: I install `numexpr` with both methods( `brew install numexpr` and `pip install numexpr` and after both, I have this package in my list:

```
% pip list                                                       
Package    Version
---------- -------
numexpr    2.8.4
numpy      1.24.2
pip        23.0.1
setuptools 66.1.1
tk         0.1.0
wheel      0.38.4
```

and used in my code like this: `import numexpr`

But I really don't know how should solve this repeated problem. I change my interpreter directory to : `/user/bin/python3` or `/opt/homebrew/bin/python3.10` or `/user/local/bin/pyhton3` which are available for me but nothing changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, you're creating a separate environment for each project and I assumed you're doing it correctly. After activating the virtual environment for the project and you're installing the packages in the active virtual environment. All seems okay until now.

However, when choosing the interpreter, you're not choosing the active env as I understand from your description. Instead, you're choosing `/user/bin/python3`etc. which is not an active environment's python path.

After creating an environment and installing your desired package for each project, I suggest you write the terminal `which python` -> and select the output path as an interpreter.

Comment: I think my comment was missed. Thank you. It worked for me and my problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

Does this problem happen with other libraries like numpy? Also I'd recommend you make a virtual environment (see python venv) and use its interpreter and pip to manage dependencies for your project

Comment: In this senarion no, numpy did not work as well. My problem is exactly in virtual environment. It didn't work correctly into it. Out of it I install numpy and it work normal.

Answer (score 0):

I would like you provide some actual python code that shows what causes the error? it's hard to tell what's happening if I don't have any code as reference. Maybe you could do 'python -m pip install pip --upgrade' and try installing, and try the same command instead of pip put the module you want to import. I just would like some more solid references to work with.

provide as much context and reference.

If it works out please let me know!

Comment: I upgraded pip before. in the first line of file I had error ```import numexpr``` . It solve by another answer, thank you for your time.